# How can I resize a QSCrollBar to change it's width in runtime?

Tags: python, pyside2, qtstylesheets, qscrollbar

I'm currently trying to reproduce the Window 10 Start Menu scroll bar in Qt (python) but I can't figure how to resize my custom QScrollBar to change it's width in runtime.

I tried to resize it using the QScrollBar.resize method (in the enterEvent and leaveEvent) but it scale the widget outside it's "drawing area".
For example, my scroll bar is set to a QScrollArea and when I try to resize it, it doesn't take more space and move the widgets, instead of that it just scale on it's right, where I can't see it.

The only solution I've found for now is to use StyleSheet but I can't animate this to have the smooth resize I'm looking for.

There is some code for you to test and see what's wrong:

```py
from PySide2 import QtWidgets, QtCore
from functools import partial

class MyTE(QtWidgets.QPlainTextEdit):
    
    def __init__(self):
        super(MyTE, self).__init__()
        
        self.setVerticalScrollBar(MyScrollBar(self))
        self.setPlainText('mmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmm'*50)
        
class MyScrollBar(QtWidgets.QScrollBar):
    
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(MyScrollBar, self).__init__(parent=parent)
        self.setSizePolicy(QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Expanding, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Expanding)        
        
    def enterEvent(self, event):
        super(MyScrollBar, self).enterEvent(event)
        
        self.resize(QtCore.QSize(4, self.height()))
        
    def leaveEvent(self, event):
        super(MyScrollBar, self).leaveEvent(event)
        
        self.resize(QtCore.QSize(10, self.height()))
        
wid = MyTE()
wid.show()
```

Comment: please provide a [mre]

Comment: Done ! Can I ask why you removed the last line of my message ? I just wanted to say thanks for the help..

Comment: Exactly for that reason. Greetings are irrelevant as the post should focus on the problem so avoid greetings, thanks, information on your level of expertise or information that is not relevant. The community understands that every member is grateful to any member of the community so it is unnecessary to indicate it explicitly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

.0I've finally found how to do it without using stylesheet !
Thanks eyllanesc for your answer, it give me a new bases to work on, I've finally understand how Qt handle the resizing (I guess), I use the `setFixedSize` in a method called everytime the value of my animation change.

To work, this need to have an overrided `sizeHint` method that return the value of the animation for the width.
Also, this works on Autodesk Maya (unfortunately the solution offered by eyllanesc didn't worked in Maya for unknown reason).

There is my solution:

```py
from PySide2 import QtWidgets, QtCore, QtGui


class MyTE(QtWidgets.QPlainTextEdit):
    def __init__(self):
        super(MyTE, self).__init__()

        self.setVerticalScrollBar(MyScrollBar(self))

        self.setPlainText("mmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmm" * 50)
        self.setSizePolicy(QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Expanding, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Expanding)

    def resizeEvent(self, event):
        super(MyTE, self).resizeEvent(event)


class MyScrollBar(QtWidgets.QScrollBar):
    
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(MyScrollBar, self).__init__(parent=parent)

        self._animation = QtCore.QVariantAnimation(
            startValue=10.0, endValue=25.0, duration=300
        )
        self._animation.valueChanged.connect(self.changeWidth)

        self._width = 10

    def enterEvent(self, event):
        super(MyScrollBar, self).enterEvent(event)
        self._animation.setDirection(QtCore.QAbstractAnimation.Forward)
        self._animation.start()

    def leaveEvent(self, event):
        super(MyScrollBar, self).leaveEvent(event)
        self._animation.setDirection(QtCore.QAbstractAnimation.Backward)
        self._animation.start()

    def sizeHint(self):
        """This must be overrided and return the width processed by the animation
        .. note:: In my final version I've replaced self.height() with 1 because it does not change 
        anything but self.height() was making my widget grow a bit each time.
        """
        return QtCore.QSize(self._width, self.height())

    def changeWidth(self, width):
        self._width = width  # This will allow us to return this value as the sizeHint width
        self.setFixedWidth(width) # This will ensure to scale the widget properly.


if __name__ == "__main__":

    app = QtWidgets.QApplication()
    wid = MyTE()
    wid.show()
    app.exec_()
```

Note: startValue and endValue of the QVariantAnimation must be float, animation won't work if they are of type int (Work in Qt 5.6.1 (Maya 2018) but not Qt 5.12.5 (Maya 2020)

PS: If someone is interrested about my final Widget (Window 10 Start menu scroll bar) let ask me in private.

Answer (score 0):

To make the width change smoother then you can use a `QVariantAnimation`:

```py
from PySide2 import QtWidgets, QtCore


class MyTE(QtWidgets.QPlainTextEdit):
    def __init__(self):
        super(MyTE, self).__init__()

        self.setVerticalScrollBar(MyScrollBar(self))

        self.setPlainText("mmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmm" * 50)


class MyScrollBar(QtWidgets.QScrollBar):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(MyScrollBar, self).__init__(parent=parent)
        self._animation = QtCore.QVariantAnimation(
            startValue=10, endValue=25, duration=500
        )
        self._animation.valueChanged.connect(self.change_width)

    def enterEvent(self, event):
        super(MyScrollBar, self).enterEvent(event)
        self._animation.setDirection(QtCore.QAbstractAnimation.Forward)
        self._animation.start()

    def leaveEvent(self, event):
        super(MyScrollBar, self).leaveEvent(event)
        self._animation.setDirection(QtCore.QAbstractAnimation.Backward)
        self._animation.start()

    def change_width(self, width):
        self.setStyleSheet("""QScrollBar:vertical{ width: %dpx;}""" % (width,))


if __name__ == "__main__":

    app = QtWidgets.QApplication()
    wid = MyTE()
    wid.show()
    app.exec_()
```

Comment: Thanks for this answer ! But if the scaling works with stylesheet, why does it does not work with the `resize` method ? I would prefer to do it that way instead of modifying my stylesheet on the fly.
Also, I'm trying to use this in Autodesk Maya but it simply doesn't scale at all, any idea ?

Comment: I've tried a lot of widget flags and it does not seems to come from there, or maybe I've missed the one.
It's really curious that stylesheet acts differently in maya than python standalone, I've also desesperately tried to call a repaint, to use setGeometry instead of resize, to modify the sizeHint method etc but nothing seems to work..